# Drag And Edit Table Component In DWG Drawing

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk, autodesk-designautomation, dwg

I am developing an application that works with DWG files for valve designs, and I need to implement the functionality of allowing users to drag and drop tables as DWG components onto the drawing and then edit those tables by modifying their data or adding new rows to them. The user should then be able to save the modified drawing at the end.

I am considering using either the Autodesk Forge Viewer API or Design Automation API to implement this functionality, but I'm not sure how to proceed with adding tables to the DWG file while previewing it in the viewer and then modifying them ( allowing user to drag table and place at desired location in drawing | we will create table dwg with existing data we have | user will have side bar along the viewer to choose the table and then place it on drawing and able to edit it).

Can anyone guide me on how to implement this functionality using either the Autodesk Forge Viewer API or Design Automation API, or any other Autodesk services that may be suitable for this purpose? I would greatly appreciate any code examples or pointers to relevant documentation.

Answer (score 1):

1. You will need to use the Design Automation API (the viewer api cannot create or modify DWG files)
2. You will need to become familiar with AutoCAD API (see https://www.autodesk.com/developer-network/platform-technologies/autocad). Design Automation is a service that simply runs your AutoCAD scripts/apps in the "cloud".